# How to add new argument in rust struct via the method?

Tags: rust

in the following example I need to conditionally create other argument called `number_3` without adding it to the struct. I wan to add this just like using `setattr(self,'number_3',number)` in python?

- **The reason** I need this because I don't want the create new object of my class like `MyClass {    number: i32,    number_2: i32, number_3:Some(None)}` this `number_3:Some(None)` is Unnecessary to add. Also, most times I will never need it it is just for some edge cases.

- Also, is it possible to initialize it with value None.

```rust
pub struct MyClass {
    number: i32,
    number_2: i32,
}

impl MyClass {
    pub fn my_function(mut self) -> i32 {
        self.number_3 = my_special_function().unwrap();
        if self.number_3 != Some(Nome) {
            return self.number * self.number_2 / self.number_3;
        } else {
            return self.number * self.number_2;
        };
    };
```

Comment: Do you need it as a parameter of `my_function()`, or as a field of `MyClass`?

Comment: I need to use it in other functions of the class.

Comment: since there is no class in rust your question is very unclear

Comment: sorry I ment struct not class

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

Besides explicitly initializing the field with `None`, you have few options:

Providing a constructor that does that (or two, for both cases):

```rust
impl MyClass {
    pub fn new(number: i32, number_2: i32) -> Self {
        Self { number, number_2, number_3: None }
    }
    pub fn with_three_numbers(number: i32, number_2: i32, number_3: i32) -> Self {
        Self { number, number_2, number_3: Some(number_3) }
    }
```

Implementing [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html) (usually by deriving it) then using the [struct update syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#creating-instances-from-other-instances-with-struct-update-syntax) to add the default. This may mean even more boilerplate in your case, but may be worthwhile in case you have many optional fields:

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MyClass { ... }

MyClass { number: 0, number_2: 1, ..MyClass::default() };
```

There were, and are, few RFCs and discussions around this subject, so you may be able to have defaulted fields in the future:

- [Issue #1594, Default values for struct fields (closed)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1594).
- [RFC #1806, Default Struct Field Values (postponed)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1806).
- [Draft RFC, Default field values](https://github.com/Centril/rfcs/pull/19).
- [Pre-RFC, User-provided default field values](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-user-provided-default-field-values/15877).